# Unable to open Chrome with View Source page through CMD(C Language)

Tags: c, google-chrome, clang

I wrote a C Program that gets a website URL from user and then opens chrome and shows Source Code. But there in an error. The program is opening chrome but not the view-source part. I tried removing the view source part and just opening the webpage and this works fine. So I am having a problem only with the view-source part. Please suggest me something

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
char URL[50], Location[100];
clrscr();
textcolor(GREEN);
printf("\t\t\t  HTML Code Viewer V0.1 Beta\n\n");
cprintf("     Please enter the website address:  ");
scanf("%s", &URL);
strcat(URL, "");
strcpy(Location, "C:\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe --new-window ");
strcat(Location, " view-source:");
strcat(Location, URL);
system(Location);
// This part is only to test wether the proper url is sent to chrome or not//
printf("%s", Location);
getch();
}
```

Comment: Just asking, is `Location[100]` sufficient?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Just after you told me I tried changing it to 250, but the result is the same so there is no problem with it

Comment: Does the system command work when you run it from the command line?

Comment: @Jongware when run through just CMD it opens new window just like the C program. It does not open the view source page.

Comment: Well then there is your problem - and it has nothing to do with your C code.

Comment: @Jongware Yes sir. So please help me fix it